# From flow B I want to call a particular view-state of flow A - Spring webflow

Tags: spring-webflow

Using Spring web-flow 2.3.0, how can I call a PARTICULAR viewstate of flow A from flow B.

Can I use subflow?

From flow B , I want to go to viewstate="def" of flow A

Flow B

```
    <subflow-state id="actions1" subflow="A">
</subflow-state>
```

Flow A

```
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">

<view-state id="abc">
</view-state>
<view-state id="def">
</view-state>
```

can someone please tell me how to do this..dint find anything over google

Comment: I have not started bounty on this question , why it is showing that "question rligible for bounty in 2 days"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, you can't.

A flow is defined as

> a reusable sequence of steps that can execute in different contexts

In this case, `def` is a flow of its own. In addition, flows are only accessible from their first state.

Consider, flow A:

```
<view-state id="searchUsersView" model="searchCriteriaWm" view="users/list">
  <transition on="selectUser" to="detailView">
     <set name="detailWm" value="usersActions.getUserDetail(searchCriteriaWm.selectedElementId)" />
  </transition>
</view-state>
```

And flow B:

```
<view-state id="createUserView" model="createUserWm" view="users/create">
  <transition on="submit" to="detailView">
    <evaluate expression="userActions.createUser(createUserWm)" result="detailWm" />
  </transition>
</view-state>
```

Instead of having two `detailViews`, you can easily create a detail flow that can be accessed as a subflow.

```
<input name="detailWm">
<view-state id="detailView" model="detailWm" view="users/detail">
</view-state>
```